# Proper way to regularly write to file which can be cleared by another process?

Tags: python, file, concurrency, atomic

I have a Python script that must write a new line (containing a number) to a file each second.

I have another program that will regularly need to archive that file, so it will probably move the file to another location (Python can for example re-create the file if it doesn't exist anymore), but any other solution is possible (the file can be copied, left in place and emptied f.e.).

What would be the proper way to ensure that everything happens atomically, i.e. that no data is lost?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's a raspberry pi, so Raspian, which is a debian.

Comment: Does your Python process close the file in between writes or does it hold it open permanently?

Comment: @mhawke it keeps it open, but I could change that

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening file with "w+" option , it will append data if file exist or create new one if file is not there.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more concerned with Python writing to the file while the file is being moved (or cleared) by the other process

Comment: Once, Python acquire permission to write in the file, it will not get deleted as Python will lock it for any modification. And if the file deletion has already started, you cannot get the permission to write into it.